# Windows-10: How to delete an item from a browser drop-down list?

Tags: windows-10, gui

**Problem Description**:

- In Chrome, loading the Gmail login page.
- The user mistakenly entered his password in the user-name field
- Now, everytime he logs back in, his password is displayed in the drop-down list, along with other user-names

Under Windows-7, it could be fixed by clicking into the user-name field, then, use the keyboard down-arrow to move to the item to be deleted, and then pressing delete.

However, this does not work anymore under Windows-10.

What is the new way to fix that problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's Windows that's causing the issue? This sounds like it's Chrome password saving. Have a look at [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) Google help article. Look for the "Delete a saved password" part.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. This is not a saved password issue. Text is being displayed in the the drop down list of the field where people can type in their email addresses. That is the list I am trying to clear. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hover the cursor over the unwanted item (the password you typed in by mistake).

Hit Shift Delete.

This is on Chrome on an HP Spectre.

I'm a total civilian, read this somewhere. I hope it works on old Gmail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of Chrome you can delete those cached data.

```
At the top right, click More More.
Click More tools and then Clear browsing data.
In the box that appears, at the top, choose a time period, such past hour or past day. To delete everything, select beginning of time.
Select the types of information you want to remove. 
Click Clear browsing data.
```

Comment: It did not work. I am not trying to delete browser data. I am trying to delete autocomplete data from Windows.

Comment: Did you tried this?

Comment: Open Internet Explorer > Internet Options > Content tab. Here click on the AutoComplete Settings button.

Comment: Yes I tried both of your suggestions. Thanks for trying to help. They didn't work. Perhaps you could recreate the problem I describe (without using your actual password) if you are curious to see what I am hoping to fix. This is Windows 10 by the way. The problem did not exist in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Edge, go to settings/advanced settings/handle passwords. Then find and delete the corresponing password that you want to delete in the list of passwords.